# No System.Runtime.Caching available?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

output type of 'Class Library', and a target framework of '.NET Framework 4'.

According to everything I've read, I should have it available, but all I'm seeing in the System.Runtime namespace is the following:

```
CompilerServices
ConstrainedExecution
ExceptionServices
Hosting
InteropServices
Remoting
Serialization
Versioning
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What specific object are you missing?  It could just be that there are similar namespaces in different assemblies.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You just need to add a reference to the `System.Runtime.Caching` assembly.

1. In solution explorer, right-click on "References"
2. Select "Add reference"
3. From left side menu select "Assemblies"
4. Look for (or filter) and add `System.Runtime.Caching.dll`.

It's not part of the default set of references in a class library, but you should be able to add it with no problems.

Comment: *sigh*  Thank you, I dove in there first thing and somehow successfully missed that the assembly was in the list.  Silly mistake.

Answer (score 17):

To complement Jon Skeets [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13615427/1042705), (for those who run into this problem),  if you *still* get red squiggly lines under `Caching` after having added reference to `System.Runtime.Caching` assembly, just restart the Visual Studio, after having saved the solution, and you should be good to go.

[image: Visual Studio red squiggly lines]

Having *added the reference*, *saved the solution* and ( *if need may be* ) ***restarted*** Visual Studio, you should be able to *use* the `types` within this `namespace`. In order to get my solution to work, I had to do this very way.

### **Edit:**

While trying to recreate the problem, and solving this way, it seems that we need to set `Copy Local` to `True` in `System.Runtime.Caching` > `Properties` and *then* restart Visual Studio for getting it to work. At least, for my case, the problem didn't seem to solve without this. ;)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - the first part didn't help any, but the additional edit part works a treat :)

Answer (score 5):

Reference `System.Runtime.Caching.dll`.  This is another one of those rather obtuse gotchas in the .NET framework right now where there will be very similar namespaces in some things, but the actual classes you want will be referenced in different assembles.  As an example, [CacheItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitem.aspx) is in this alternate DLL, whereas [ApplicationActivator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.hosting.applicationactivator.aspx) (in System.Runtime.Hosting) is in mscorlib.

Answer (score 3):

For me the [System.Runtime.Caching NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Caching) is what I needed
little bit o this and all was well

```
dotnet add package System.Runtime.Caching --version 5.0.0
```