# No system.runtime.caching in UWP

Tags: c#, caching, uwp

I was looking for implementing caching in my UWP app, but I couldn't find the System.Runtime.Caching, I looked at msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185505.aspx couldn't find this reference. Is this supported on UWP? if not what is the alternative? I looked at other similar questions on the stackoverflow but couldn't find any viable answer on [No System.Runtime.Caching available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615407/no-system-runtime-caching-available)

Comment: doesn't Microsoct.Extensions.MemoryCache work on UWP? You can also use CacheManager which should be working, the build in Dictionary basec cache or using the Microsoft Extensions should totally work I guess

Comment: I couldn't reference Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll in my UWP project. I can use dictionary, but I need to have expiration of some some key value pair e.g. shared access signatutre that will get invalid after sometime.

Comment: Don't get what you mean but you can just add nuget packages to your UWP project, I just created a blank one and added CacheManager.Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory and used it. Works totally fine

Comment: yes, Got it installed, later I found it was because of System.Runtime version mismatch

Comment: you might have to update the UWP Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package to make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Runtime.Caching is not available in the current UWP SDK release. Depending on what type of caching you need, there are several options:

UI caching:

- [Page.NavigationCacheMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode): remembers the rendering of the page on the backstack (including scrolling position, data on screen, ...).
- [UIElement.CacheMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.cachemode): rendering the content of a UIElement as a bitmap (mainly for complex renderings).

'Real' data caching, using 3rd party libraries like:

- [Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache): asynchronous key-value store based on SQLite, with expiration rules.
- Save the data in JSON/XML format to the disk yourself.

---

Update on comment:

You can clear the NavigationCacheMode by setting it to `Disabled`. Note that you can't pass a parameter on the GoBack() to tell your previous page to clear the cache. So you'll have to add some sort of event messaging (e.g. Prism EventAggregator) or a global variable to track that as well.

> If you want to change the value of NavigationCacheMode programmatically to Enabled or Required, you can only set these values in the constructor for the page.
>
> If you change the value of `NavigationCacheMode` from `Required` or `Enabled` to `Disabled`, the page is flushed from the cache.

But since you're talking about JSON data from a web call, I'd go for Akavache.

Comment: I need to store the Json data that is returned by my web app. I tried the Page.NavigationCacheMode, is there a way to purge the page cache, e.g. screen 2 modifies some data that needs to updated to previous screen, I couldn't find any doc/example of the same

Comment: Updated answer. But as you're talking about retrieving json from Web, do look at Akavache .. in my opinion it's a much better solution.

Comment: Thanks everyone! will  evaluate akavacache