# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Cannot find Cache object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to use caching in ASP.NET MVC 5, I can't find which object is to be used outside of the controller.

I don't want to use `[OutputCache]`, I want to store some data from the database in the server's cache.

How do I do that? Which object do I use?

Comment: [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Refer also [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/stephenmuecke/f24ab8a940d61035f711429a530376a8) for a wrapper class

Comment: `System.Runtime.Caching` is not installed by default, seems a bit weird to me that you need to install an extra library to get access to caching in that way, am I wrong?

Comment: It's also come with .Net Framework. You don't need to install a package if you're targeting the .Net Framework.

Comment: Just use the traditional add reference.

Comment: i didn't find a nuget package for it. I needed to add the Reference in the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615407/no-system-runtime-caching-available